# Calculator gives wrong answers for log

Tags: logarithms

$10^3 = 1000$

My calculator with $10\log(1000)$ gives $30$

$15^4 = 50625$.

My calculator with $15\log(50625)$ gives $70.57$.

What am I doing wrong? Or would there be something wrong with my properties? I am using a Casio fx-82MS.

Thanks in advance,

Jarno

Comment: Well $\log(50625) \approx 4.704$ so your calculator is right. But your reasoning is not !

Comment: in the second line, you are multipying 10 by the number you want. log just means log with a base of ten. the 10 and 15 headers are unnecessary.

Comment: $10Log(1000)  = Log(1000^{10}) = Log((10^3)^{10}) = Log(10 ^ {30}) = 30$

Comment: Hmm.. so how will I go back to 15^4 with the log function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the base-15 log of 50625, you need to calculate $(\log 50625) ÷ (\log15)$. If you do this you'll get the answer 4.

Similarly if you calculate $(\log 1000) ÷ (\log 10)$ you will get 3.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculator interprets $10\log(1000)$ as $10$ TIMES $\log(1000)$, so $10$ times $3$. This is not completely unreasonable, given how $10x$ is short for $10$ times $x$ etc.

See the other answer for how to remedy this problem.